# Is there a way to type the symbol Θ (theta) in Linux using an Irish keyboard?

Tags: linux, keyboard, typing

How can I type the symbol [Θ (theta)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta) on an Irish keyboard layout (mostly the same as UK layout) using Linux? Seems a lot of hassle to go copy and paste it from somewhere everytime I need it,.

Comment: why don't you use the character map ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Linux (Gnome), press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, then type <kbd>U</kbd>. After that, you enter the hex Unicode value. For Theta, this is 398. (The symbol will not appear until you press another key, such as <kbd>space</kbd>. This is reasonable: you may want more digits, such as U+3987, 㦇.)

Comment: Just does not work for me (Ubuntu 10.04, Gnome of course)

Comment: Sorry, it's ctrl+shift, not ctrl+alt

Comment: Still doesn't work for me (in plain gedit); also, it's better to just fix the errors when editing because, for example, it took me *three* reads to notice the change.

Comment: Sorry about the editing. So, when you press and hold ctrl+shift, and you press "u", do you get an underlined "u" on your screen? if so, all you have to do, while keeping the keys pressed, is enter 398. At least that is how it works for me. Did you do it like that?

Comment: Ahem. Yes, the underlined "u" appears, and when I type 398 *after* that, theta is typed. But it does not work without the "u", and you did not mention that in your answer. Also, you do not need to keep Ctrl+Shift pressed, you can release them and press Enter after typing "398" too.

Comment: Just realized that. Fixed my answer now. Seems like I was slightly confused.